# Extraneous curve due to MeshFunctions

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I was using `MeshFunctions` to get intersection of quadratic with plane, but am getting some unexpected curves, any idea how to get rid of them, or maybe a more elegant way to achieve this effect?

[image]

```
genPlot[theta_] := (
   plot1 = 
    Plot3D[3 x^2 + y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
     MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, If[#1 != 0, ArcTan[#1, #2], -1] &}, 
     MeshStyle -> {Automatic, Thick}, 
     Mesh -> {5, {theta, theta - Pi}}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
     RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 3], 
     PlotPoints -> 25];
   point = 2 {Cos[theta], Sin[theta], 0};
   
   plot2 = 
    Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], EdgeForm[None], 
      Polygon[{-point, point, 
        point + {0, 0, 10}, -point + {0, 0, 10}}]}];
   Show[plot1, plot2, SphericalRegion -> True]
   );
genPlot[Pi/4]
```

**edit**
Brett's solution below fixes it ([notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-quadratic-slice-animation.nb))

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`MeshFunctions` works by detecting where the function crosses your values, in this case where `ArcTan` becomes equal to `theta`.  Unfortunately this is done numerically, checking sign changes, and so the branch cut along the negative $y$ axis is included.  (It goes from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, so must have crossed `theta` somewhere in there, right?)

The cleanest solution I've found for removing it in your example is to rotate the branch cut to align along where you want to draw the mesh line by using `Mod[ArcTan[#1, #2], 2 Pi, theta]` for the mesh function:

```
genPlot[theta_] := (plot1 = 
    Plot3D[3 x^2 + y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
     MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, Mod[ArcTan[#1, #2], 2 Pi, theta] &}, 
     MeshStyle -> {Automatic, Thick}, 
     Mesh -> {5, {theta, theta + Pi}}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
     RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 3], 
     PlotPoints -> 25];
   point = 2 {Cos[theta], Sin[theta], 0};
   plot2 = 
    Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], EdgeForm[None], 
      Polygon[{-point, point, 
        point + {0, 0, 10}, -point + {0, 0, 10}}]}];
   Show[plot1, plot2, SphericalRegion -> True]);
genPlot[Pi/4]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! BTW, any tips how to get rid of that artifact on the left edge of the bowl? (right above the bold curve)

Comment: This gets rid of that artifact: `Plot3D[3 x^2 + y^2, {x, y} \[Element] 
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Disk[{0, 0}, Sqrt[3]], AccuracyGoal -> 5], opts]`, where `opts` omits the `RegionFunction` option. Note that the call to `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` is not necessary, but I added it to make the boundary smoother.

Comment: @chip thanks! Curious, how did you come up with this idea?

Comment: Just happened to know the syntax. It would be nice if the boundary by default was just as smooth as what we get with `RegionFunction`.