# Spiral gridding in Plot3D

Tags: plotting, grid-lines

I would like to represent a curved manifold with a "frame dragging", such as this one ([source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277326936_Simulation_of_Flares_from_the_Galactic_Center_Black_Hole)):

[image]

I have done the following:

```
Plot3D[1 - 8/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] , {x, -8, 8}, {y, -8, 8}, Boxed -> False,
  Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-8, 8}, {-8, 8}}]
```

[image]

How can I make a gridding with spiral-like shape?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**

I found that involute of circle also work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute

```
r[m_, s_] = {Cos[s + m], Sin[s + m]};
involute[m_, s_] = r[m, s] + s*Normalize[Derivative[0, 1][r][m, s]];
ParametricPlot[
 Table[involute[m, s], {m, Subdivide[2 π, 8]}], {s, 0, 7}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Disk[]}]
```

[image]

```
{x, y} = involute[m, s];
ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, 1 - 8/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, {m, 0, 2 π}, {s, 
  0, 10}, MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, Mesh -> {Subdivide[2 π, 8]}, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> None, 
 Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image]

**Original**

To make the lines does not overlay, we use equiangular spiral.

```
{n, v} = {10, 1};
p0 = CirclePoints[8, n];
p = Table[r[i][t], {i, n}];
sol = NDSolve[{D[p, t] == 
     v*Normalize /@ (RotateLeft[p] - p), (p /. t -> 0) == p0, 
    WhenEvent[Norm[r[1][t]] < .1, {Sow[t], "StopIntegration"}]}, 
   p, {t, 0, 25}];
plot = ParametricPlot[p /. sol, {t, 0, 25}]
```

[image]

```
vortex = 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate@
   Table[{Indexed[p[[i]], 1], Indexed[p[[i]], 2], 
      1 - 8/Sqrt[Indexed[p[[i]], 1]^2 + Indexed[p[[i]], 2]^2]} /. 
     sol, {i, 1, n}], {t, 0, 25}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-8, 8}, {-8, 8}}, Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Feel free to update this answer with physical `drag`, here is only the way to go:

```
drag[r_] := 1/r + 1;

ParametricPlot3D[
 {r Cos[ t drag[r]], r Sin[ t drag[r]], 1 - 8/r},
 {r, 1, 8}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-8, 8}, {-8, 8}}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Take the example from [ParametricPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html). It look that way

```
drag[r_] := 1/r + 1;

Table[ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t drag[r]], r Sin[t drag[r]], 
   1 - 8/r}, {r, 1, 8}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-8, 8}, {-8, 8}}, MeshFunctions -> {f}, 
  Mesh -> 5], {f, {Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, x], 
   Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, y], Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, z], 
   Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, u], Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, v]}}]
```

[image: different mesh functions one for the purposes of the question]

This allow the particles on the spirals inward to excape:

```
gericPlot[
   theta_] := (plot1 = 
    Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
     MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, 
       Mod[Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2] ArcTan[#1, #2], Pi, theta] &}, 
     MeshStyle -> {Automatic, Thick}, 
     Mesh -> {15, {theta, theta + Pi/3, theta + Pi/2, theta + 2 Pi/3, 
        theta + Pi}}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
     RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 3], 
     PlotPoints -> 25];
   point = 2 {Cos[theta], Sin[theta], 0};
   plot2 = 
    Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], EdgeForm[None], 
      Polygon[{-point, point, 
        point + {0, 0, 10}, -point + {0, 0, 10}}]}];
   Show[plot1, plot2, SphericalRegion -> True]);
gericPlot[\[Pi]]
```

[image: spirals plots on the given potential, surface]

This uses Plot3D and MeshFunctions. Here this are two meshfunctions on the surface. These are circles and spirals. It is inspired from [extraneous curve due to meshfunctions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255501/extraneous-curve-due-to-meshfunctions). The parameter $\theta$ allows control over
how the curves behave and where they are. Arctan is in need and has to be nonsingular in the argument. Such a phase a $\theta$ is needed.

The first and the second demonstration can be combined. Have fun.

Have a look at this answer from me for adding labels in Plot3D: [adding z value to mesh lines in plot3d](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/227854/adding-z-value-to-mesh-lines-in-plot3d).